# What is the opposite of 初心者?

Tags: word-choice, words, word-requests

As in, I want to say veterans/old hats at doing something instead of beginners at doing something.

Edit: Thank you for all the responses. I wasn't looking to imply skill, so I think 経験者 is the word I am looking for, but I learned a lot of other great words through the responses.

Comment: This is a pretty uncommon choice, and not really "the opposite" 初心者, so probably not a great answer, but I really like the word 老練 (which explicitly has the "old" nuance to it, so don't use it for someone young). :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word I hear most common for this is: ベテラン.

The second one: 経験者{けいけんしゃ}.

Answer (score 17):

I think it's [熟練者]{じゅくれんしゃ}...

[Source](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/antonym/content/%E5%88%9D%E5%BF%83%E8%80%85)

Comment: I'd never heard that word before, so thank you. Though I think for what I was trying to get at, 経験者 is most appropriate.

Comment: Oh, in that case, I think you should accept macraf's answer.

Comment: I will change it because there seems to be a small consensus that I should; however, I just want it stated for the record that I chose this one because it seemed the best answer to the question I actually asked. I was thinking of future searchers.

Answer (score 11):

This depends on context.  At this point I would say macraf's answer (particularly 経験者) is the best (at least in my findings), but if we are indeed talking about skill involved (IE, you can rank someone, like in a game)　中級者 and 上級者 must also be considered.

Again, considering the context (perhaps you can give a bit more?) none of these may sound natural.

Comment: 経験者 sounds like what I was looking for... experience, rather than indication of skill. Thank you, though, those are also excellent words to know.

Answer (score 4):

Again, depending on context, other possible terms include 玄人【くろうと】 and 専門家【せんもんか】.

Comment: OP may be interested to know that 玄人 is also more obviously an antonym of 素人【しろうと】.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking to say someone who is very good at certain thing, then how about 達人【たつじん】? I hear that often.

Answer (score 4):

You guys are all correct! :)

I would use 経験者（けいけんしゃ）. It really depends on the context. I'll list the ones that weren't in this thread.

- エキスパート（expert in katakana has the same meaning as in English）
- プロ（professional）
- 腕利き（うできき）
- カリスマ（someone who is really good that he/she is almost revered.）

As you might know, a lot of English words are borrowed today, so it might be useful to know these words.

Answer (score 3):

People also use プロ quite widely. I once tried to ask a host family if I could say 素人 and 玄人, and my host mother laughed and told me that nobody used 玄人 - only  プロ。